# Many-to-many relation - automatically delete orphans

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

Assume a many-to-many relation between team and player. This is modelled by the following tables:

```
create table team
(
    identifier integer primary key
);

create table player
(
    identifier integer primary key
);

create table member
(
    team_identifier integer,
    player_identifier integer,

    primary key(team_identifier, player_identifier),
    foreign key(team_identifier) references team on update cascade on delete cascade,
    foreign key(player_identifier) references player on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

Assume the following data:

```
insert into team values(1);
insert into team values(2);

insert into player values(1);

insert into member values(1, 1);
insert into member values(2, 1);
```

Let's delete the teams:

```
delete from team where identifier = 1;
delete from team where identifier = 2;
```

Now we have a player without a team. Is there a way to automatically delete this player? That is, when the deletion of a team results in an orphan player, this player should be removed as well (but not the other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ideal solution to settle your problem
create after-delete trigger or update in membre:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_player_not_in_member() RETURNS trigger AS $delete_player_not_in_member$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM player WHERE Identifier NOT IN (SELECT player_identifier FROM membre);
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$delete_player_not_in_member$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_player_not_in_member AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE ON member
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_player_not_in_member();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not necessarily. The player could still be considered a player who needs a team if you plan on adding him to a team at a later time. Or, if you want a pull of available players.

However, you could try using

```
DELETE FROM member WHERE team_identifier = 1
DELETE FROM member WHERE team_identifier = 2

DELETE FROM player
WHERE Identifier NOT IN (SELECT player_identifier FROM member)
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question. I want orphan player(s) to be deleted **automatically** after deleting team(s).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple is to add a trigger which tracks team deletions, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER drop_orphan_player
  AFTER DELETE ON team FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE FROM player 
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT player_id FROM member
  );
```

See it working at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b097/1/0).